# Is a compact Hausdorff space metrizable? Maybe even complete?

Tags: general-topology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A compact Hausdorff space that is not metrizable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74923/a-compact-hausdorff-space-that-is-not-metrizable)

Is it true that every topological space $X$ that is Hausdorff and compact is also metrizable? Maybe even complete?
What is the relationship between the completeness and the compactness in a metric space ?

I'm not asking this question out of nowhere. The reason is that almost every theorem I have encountered lately about compact metric spaces could easily be generalized to compact Hausdorff space but also some theorems I encountered about complete metrics have a counterpart for compact Hausdorff spaces  (e.g. Baire's theorem).

Comment: A simple example is an uncountable product of a two-point discrete space with itself. This is Hausdorff and compact, because these are preserved by products, but it is not second-countable, and thus not metrizable, because a compact metric space is second-countable.

Comment: By Urysohn's metrization theorem, a second countable compact Hausdorff space is metrizable. Since every compact metric space is second countable and Hausdorff, this means that a compact Hausdorff space is metrizable iff it is second-countable. There is also a result that a metrizable space is compact if and only if every metric metrizing it is complete. I don't know a reference for this result.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, take $\omega_1+1=[0,\omega_1]$ with the order topology ($\omega_1$ is the smallest uncountable ordinal). It is not metrizable, since the character of $\omega_1$ is uncountable. Another example is the Stone-Čech compactification $\beta \mathbb{N}$ of natural numbers.

Each compact space is Čech-complete. A metrizable space space is Čech-complete if and only if it is homeomorphic to a complete metric space. Any Čech-complete space is a Baire space.

Comment: Thanks. But could you maybe also provide an answer to the questions, as to what is the connection between the completeness and compactness of a metric space ?

Comment: Done (to the best of my knowledge).

Comment: @resu: Čech-completeness is the best answer to what compact and completely metrizable spaces have in common, but it might also be pointed out that a metric (not just metrizable) space is compact iff it is both complete and totally bounded.

Comment: Could you provide me with a (decent) reference, where I can find more about Cech-completeness ? Wikipedia doesn't seem to have anything and the "topospace"-wiki is rather poor.

Comment: "General topology" by R. Engelking.

Comment: @resu: There’s a good discussion in Ryszard Engelking, *General Topology*, which is one of the most comprehensive reference texts around. Unfortunately, it may be hard to find. I don’t immediately find anything useful on-line.

Comment: ok, thank you very much.

Answer (score 8):

To address your second question in perhaps a simpler way than Daria's answer: every compact metric space is complete.  This is easy to prove using the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem: any Cauchy sequence $\{x_n\}$ has a subsequence that converges to some point $x$.  Then use the triangle inequality to show that the original sequence $\{x_n\}$ must converge to $x$.

Of course the converse is false: there are complete metric spaces which are not compact.  $\mathbb{R}$, for example.