# Does compact Hausdorff imply Polish?

Tags: general-topology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is a compact Hausdorff space metrizable? Maybe even complete?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83652/is-a-compact-hausdorff-space-metrizable-maybe-even-complete)

We know that a second countable locally compact Hausdorff space is a [Polish space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_space). Does
compact Hausdorff also imply Polish?

Comment: You can find counterexamples here" [A compact Hausdorff space that is not metrizable](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74923/a-compact-hausdorff-space-that-is-not-metrizable) and [Is a compact Hausdorff space metrizable? Maybe even complete?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83652/is-a-compact-hausdorff-space-metrizable-maybe-even-complete/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No: $\omega_1+1$ with the order topology is compact and Hausdorff but not even first countable, let alone metrizable.

**Added:** $\beta\Bbb N$, the Čech-Stone compactification of the natural numbers with the discrete topology, is another example, and it’s even separable.

Comment: Thanks, but what is the "weakast" assumption we have to add in order that a compact Hausdorff space is polish? As already mentioned, we know that second countability suffices, but is it also necessary?

Comment: @Andy: Yes, in the sense that every Polish space is automatically second countable. Any condition that (together with compactness and Hausdorffness) implies metrizability would do, and second countability is the simplest choice.