# Is every Hausdorff space metric?

Tags: general-topology

My question is very simple.

I know every metric space is Hausdorff, but the converse is true? anyone knows some counterexample?

Thanks

Comment: [examples of $T_2$ spaces that are not metrizable](http://topology.jdabbs.com/search?q=%7B%22and%22%3A%5B%7B%223%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%7B%2253%22%3Afalse%7D%5D%7D)

Comment: Every metric space has a *countable* basis of neighborhoods around any of its points (namely balls of radius $1/n$).

Comment: @Berci which means Hausdorff, no?

Comment: Which means look for a counterexample that has so many neighbourhoods around a point that there's no countable basis there.  That motivates looking at uncountable ordinals.

Comment: Or: [A perfect Hausdorff space that is not metrizable.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/926463), or [Example of Hausdorff and Second Countable Space that is Not Metrizable](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1029110), or other examples that you would find if bothered to search.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the space $X = \{0,1\}^\mathbb R$ of all functions from $\mathbb R$ to $\{0,1\}$ (actually any uncountable set would do in place of $\mathbb R$).  The topology is the product topology, i.e. a base is the **cylinder sets**, the sets obtained by specifying the values of the function at finitely many points.  This is Hausdorff, indeed for any $x \ne y \in X$ there is some $t \in \mathbb R$ such that $x(t) \ne y(t)$. 
It is not metrizable because no point can have a countable base of neighbourhoods: the intersection of a countable collection of cylinder sets containing $x$ will still contain lots of points besides $x$, because it only 
restricts the values at countably many members of $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 2):

The ordinal $\omega_1+1$ with the order topology is Hausdorff but not metrizable.