# Proper $G$-spaces second coutable

Tags: general-topology, group-theory

Let $G$ be a discrete countable group and $X$ a proper (cocompact, locally-compact and hausdorff if necessary) $G$-space. Then $X$ is supposed to be second countable but I dont quite see why.

Thank you.

Comment: cocompact? what is a proper $G$-space?

Comment: Why is this supposed to be true? (It is not.)

Comment: I tried to prove this for a while. Can you provide us a counterexample?

Comment: $G=\{1\}$, $X$ is any Hausdorff nonmetrizable compact space. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74923/a-compact-hausdorff-space-that-is-not-metrizable